# How to verify a target="_blank" link using selenium?

Tags: selenium

Some links on our page open in a new window using target="_blank". How can I make selenium look at the right window so I can verify that the page is linking to the right page?

Here's what I've been trying:

```
open                /page/
click               link=Find us on Facebook!
pause               2000
selectWindow        title=window title
verifyTextPresent   some text
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Selenium, so I cannot possibly give an actual answer. However, as a general comment on web design, I recommend against the `target` attribute, using any value. The 'M' in HTML is 'Markup'; HTML should not specify behavior, only meaning. For an external link, I recommend using `rel="external"`, and then JavaScript to make such links open in a new window. [Example](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/standards-compliant-world/3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass a parameter to selectWindow. The browser will automatically give your new window focus, you just need to tell selenium that it's changed. Also make sure you give your new window enough time to actually load before verifying anything:

```
open                /page
click               link=Find us on Facebook!
pause               1000
selectWindow
verifyTextPresent   some text
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    $this->click('css=.sf_admin_action_page:first a');

    $this->waitForPopUp('_blank');
    $this->selectWindow('_blank');

    $this->waitForElementPresent('css=.t-info:contains(xxx2)');
```

// ps. selenium2

Comment: what commands should I use in phpUnit to achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `selectPopUp` to focus the new window. see its document:

selectPopUp:

- Arguments:
      windowID - an identifier for the popup window, which can take on a number of different meanings
- Simplifies the process of selecting a popup window (and does not offer functionality beyond what selectWindow() already provides).

  - If windowID is either not specified, or specified as "null", the first non-top window is selected. The top window is the one that would be selected by selectWindow() without providing a windowID . This should not be used when more than one popup window is in play.
  - Otherwise, the window will be looked up considering windowID as the following in order: 1) the "name" of the window, as specified to window.open(); 2) a javascript variable which is a reference to a window; and 3) the title of the window. This is the same ordered lookup performed by selectWindow .

Answer (score 0):

I took slightly different approach which was to force any links to use target = _self so that they could be tested in the same window :

```
protected void testTextLink(WebDriver driver, final String linkText, final String targetPageTitle, final String targetPagePath) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText));

    // ensure that link always opens in the current window
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', arguments[1]);", link, "_self");

    link.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(targetPageTitle));

    // check the target page has the expected title
    assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), targetPageTitle);
    // check the target page has path
    assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(targetPagePath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code.

```
public void newtab(){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\eclipse\\chromeDriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp");

//I have provided a sample link. Make sure that you have provided the correct link in the above line.

driver.findElement(By.className("tryitbtn")).click();

new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();


// In keyboard we will press 

//ctrl+1 for 1st tab

//ctrl+2 for 2nd tab

//ctrl+3 for 3rd tab.

//Same action is written in the above code.

}
//Now you can verify the text by using testNG

Assert.assertTrue(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Case we can use KeyPress

keyPress(locator, keySequence)
    Arguments:

```
    locator - an element locator
    keySequence - Either be a string("\" followed by the numeric keycode of the key to be pressed, normally the ASCII value of that key), or a single character. For example: "w", "\119". [Give for CTRL+T]

Simulates a user pressing and releasing a key.
```