# Selenium Web Driver using PHPUnit to open a currently firefox window from a link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am using selenium web driver using phpunit, the problem I am facing right now is that I have a link button and when I click this button the current link is opened in a new page and I have no idea about how to oen the currently opened new page, can some one help me about how can I code in PHPUnit to open the currently new opened page

Comment: May the below link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282043/how-to-verify-a-target-blank-link-using-selenium

Comment: This is not help because waitForPopup and SelectWindow are not functions of webdriver and can't be used, Is there someone how can help me resolve the specific problem please

Answer (score 0):

Use "WindowHandles" in PHPunit function

Here is the solution to navigate between the tabs:

If there are two opened tabs in your browser and you want to switch to the next tab, below code will work:

$window_handles = $this->windowHandles();

$this->window($window_handles[1]);

And if you want to switch back to the previous tab just change the index as shown below :

$window_handles = $this->windowHandles();

$this->window($window_handles[0]);